# Where Does Build run for Bamboo?

Tags: devops, bamboo

I am using Bamboo for the first time. Where does the Build run on ? Bamboo Server ? Or can we trigger a Build to run on a Build machine that we define through a Bamboo defined Build Plan ?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to find in their high level docs, but the default is yes - builds run on "agents", and by default you get Local Agents which run as processes on the same server bamboo is installed on.

To run parts of your build, or all of it, on remote servers, you use what they call "Remote Agents".  There is some software you need to install on the remote machine, and your license needs to allow for remote agents.  The number of remote agents you get varies depending on what level of license you purchased.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamkb/difference-between-local-agents-and-remote-agents-457703602.html

Comment: That helps. Thanks.Can you also comment on the Scalability of Bamboo ? Hou many parallel builds can it handle at a time ? Does it support a Que System where the builds may have to wait for their turn ? I also want to have a UI wrapper around bamboo. Is that possible using the REST APIs for Bamboo ?

Comment: This page helps you to identify the necessary System requirements & considerations based on the User scenario -
 https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/bamboo-best-practice-system-requirements-388401170.html

Comment: @Chetan - yes to all of that.  Read through the documentation on agents.  Local agents have a queue, and you can even control what jobs can run on which queues.  I have seen a Bamboo instance with hundreds of projects building about five or six concurrently - generally short builds.  When you have teams with long running builds that's always an issue with shared CI tool.  Yes REST API is extensive.

Answer (score 0):

When you starts the build, it going to Build Queue and waiting for first suitable Build Agent to take it. You can see the list of agents and builds in queue if you have administrator's permissions. Also, you can see list of agents able to take certain build in Requirements pane of a Build Job configuration.